# Embedding Script in C++

Tags: c++, scripting, embedding

I have a quit big c++ program and I want to have a function which I can edit in a text file to change the behavior of my c++ program without compiling it again.

To achieve this I thought I could embed a script in my c++ program.

My function should take two c++ objects and return a boolean in relation to the two objects and their members.
The pseudo code would be similar to the following:

```
//In c++ program
CppObject cpp1, cpp2;
ScSriptObject o1 = transform(cpp1);
ScriptObject o2 = transform(cpp2);
boolean result = call function(o1, o2);

//Script function in text file
boolean function(Object o1, Object o2)
{
return do_something(o1, o2)
}
```

I would like to know if there is another maybe better solution. And with which scripting languages can this be done easily and how can it be done?

I have already taken a look at python and Python/C API, but I had some troubles to get the basic examples working and I'm wondering if there is a simpler option.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're basically asking how to write an interpreter. This is the subject of several months of an advanced programming class.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to implement it myself. I want to use an already existing one.

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using linux, you could use `system` function to call for an external script which you could edit whenever you decide to, without compiling again. Eg.:

```
int res = system("/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh");
if (res == 0)
{
    // exited normally
}
else
{
    // abnormal exit
}
```

On windows you could use a similar approach, as system in platform independent. One more thing, mind the endianness of the result!
For further reading about system, you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900666/system-calls-in-c-and-their-roles-in-programming#900685) or this almost full explanatory [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) on cplusplus.com.
Hope it helps, cheers.